# AWS S3 Bucket Lifecycle configuration Rule to Failing move contents to Glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lifecycle

I have a S3 bucket, with a single lifecycle rule called 'Put-Legacy-Backups-On-Ice'.

The life cycle rule states that on Day 1 - 'Objects move to Glacier Flexible Retrieval (formerly Glacier)'

and then on Day 93 - Objects expire

Currently I'm not seeing that objects in this bucket are getting transitioned to Glacier class after the first day

[image]

Here's a screenshot of the objects view

[image]

The lifecycle rule has been Enabled on the bucket

[image]

Comment: The rules do not work immediately. Check in few days, as there can be a marked delay.

Comment: Check again after 48 hours.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check again in 48hrs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes @marcin and @John-Rotenstein, it did appear after 48 hrs that the storage classes were all changed to Glacier. Thanks both your comments were correct.